# Progressive aspect with simple past

Tags: grammaticality, sequence-of-tenses, progressive-aspect

Is this sentence correct?

> She *isn't feeling* well so she *had* to take a day off.

Or should it be *wasn't*?

Comment: It's correct if we are talking about today (ignoring the fact that she may have started to feel better since this morning!)

Answer (score 1):

It could be *wasn't*: that would tell us nothing about whether she was feeling better now.

*Isn't* tells us that as well as being the reason for taking a day off, that is her current state.